# Ajax request fail - retrieve user id from server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have form that has one text input field and a button. On submit form, I take the value from the text field `user` and make an ajax call to `ajax.php` to then have the server return the `userID`. The server is indeed returning a value as shown in the console. But I am not sure why the ajax call is failing on each request after submitting the form. What can I correct or change to have a success?

index.php

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
     var searchUser = $('input[name="user"]').val();
     var getUser = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {user: searchUser},
        dataType:'text'
     });
     getUser.done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
     });
     getUser.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, data ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
     });
});

<form id="search" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="GET">
    <label for="user"> Username:</label><input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $user ?>"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

ajax.php

```
 if(!empty($_GET['user'])){
        $user = $_GET['user'];
        echo getInstaID($user); // this prints a numeric value like 2057821
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the data is being returned as json or jsonp? You have specified dataType: 'text'. If the return datatype is different it will error out. If you are using a fairly recent version (I think 2.0 or better) leaving out dataType or specifying dataType:"auto" will allow the call to succeed. Then you can debug to figure out how to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a success function like the following:

```
   $('form').submit(function(e) {

     var searchUser = $('input[name="user"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
         url: "ajax.php",
         data: {user: searchUser},
         success:function(data){//begin success function

        //do something with the data returned from ajax.php file
        alert(data);

    }//end success function

 });
```